Call Back Error:updating graph.figure in Plotly Dash
I tried to visualise the stock data using candle light chart in plotly, dash. But the chart doesn't showup throwing call back error. This is the first time I'm using plotly. So not sure how to get it fixed.
The chart works well if I pull data from the csv file but not showing up when pulled the data direcly from database table. Any help on this will be much useful.
Here is my code:
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd


app = Dash(__name__)

conn = sqlite3.connect('stocks.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Apple stock candlestick chart'),
    dcc.Checklist(
        id='toggle-rangeslider',
        options=[{'label': 'Include Rangeslider',
                  'value': 'slider'}],
        value=['slider']
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input("toggle-rangeslider", "value"))
def display_candlestick(value):
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT Datetime, Open, High, Low, Close FROM stock_data WHERE Symbol = ?", conn, params=('AAPL',))   


    fig = go.Figure(go.Candlestick(
        x=df['Datetime'],
        open=df['Open'],
        high=df['High'],
        low=df['Low'],
        close=df['Close']
    ))
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis_rangeslider_visible='slider' in value
    )

    return fig


app.run_server(debug=True)



Could you please add the error message to the question?

Is it working when you remove the lines fig.update_layout( ... ) ? This could help to differ between an error from your input or the output
